# How to add a delay in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following code for expansion of child menu, I need 2 seconds delay in it. How can I do so?

I tried adding it at the end of each individual command but it's not working.

```js
$('.has-children').children('a').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
  if (!checkWindowWidth()) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  const selected = $(this)

  if (selected.next('ul').hasClass('is-hidden')) {
    //desktop version only
    selected
      .addClass('selected')
      .next('ul')
      .removeClass('is-hidden')
      .end()
      .parent('.has-children')
      .parent('ul')
      .addClass('moves-out')

    selected
      .parent('.has-children')
      .siblings('.has-children')
      .children('ul')
      .addClass('is-hidden')
      .end()
      .children('a')
      .removeClass('selected')

    $('.cd-overlay').addClass('is-visible')
  }
  else {
    selected
      .removeClass('selected')
      .next('ul')
      .addClass('is-hidden')
      .end()
      .parent('.has-children')
      .parent('ul')
      .removeClass('moves-out')

    $('.cd-overlay').removeClass('is-visible')
  }

  toggleSearch('close')
})
```

Comment: on css for each class of those add `transition-duration : 2s` OR `transition-delay : 2s`

Comment: You could use `.delay(2000)` or use `setTimeout()`. Might want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve